# What is the difference between `@attr!="value"` and `not(@attr="value")` in XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

There is a HTML like this.

```
<div class="paginate_box">
  <span class="disabled prev_page">Back</span>
  <span class="current">1</span>
  <a rel="next" href="page2">2</a>
  <a rel="next" href="page3">3</a>
  <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="page2">Next</a>
</div>
```

To get biggest number of the pages I wrote this.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//div[@class="paginate_box"]/a[not(@class="next_page")]').last.text
#=> "3"
```

At first I wrote `a[@class!="next_page"]` instead of `a[not(@class="next_page")]`, but it didn't match the tag. Why it doesn't match? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem here is you are trying to use `!=` on an attribute (`@class`) that is only present on the last node. This means `@class` cannot be compared on the other nodes because it is essentially saying nothing != 'next_page'.

Since nothing is not comparable to anything, operators (including `!=` and `=`) will always return false.

In your `not` function you are asking if nothing = 'next_page' which is always `false` (as explained above) and thus `not` makes it `true` and the element is selected.

You can prove this by adding a class to one of the other anchor tags and then use the `!=` version.

Side note you can simplify the code to just use `xpath`

```
doc.xpath('//div[@class="paginate_box"]/a[not(@class="next_page")][last()]').text 
#=> "3"
# Or  
doc.xpath('//div[@class="paginate_box"]/a[not(@class="next_page")][last()]/text()').to_s
#=> "3"
```

Also if next_page anchor is always present and always last and the highest page number always precedes it then you can avoid the condition altogether:

```
doc.xpath('//div[@class="paginate_box"]/a[position()=last()-1]').text
#=> "3"
```

Here we are saying find the anchor in the position right before the last one in that div.

Alternative:

```
doc.xpath('//div[@class="paginate_box"]/a[last()]/preceding-sibling::a[1]').text
#=> "3"
```

This will find the last anchor then all the anchor siblings preceding it in bottom up order and we are selecting the first one in that list.